# shell script to find filenames in a folder(with subfolders) matching a string

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems

I want to write a shell script that matches the filenames to a given string that I enter in the command line during runtime. I want to be able to match patterns in a filename.
Like if the string is 'questi' and the folder contains 'question1.c', 'question2.c', questions.doc' those should get displayed as the answer.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Answer (score 1):

The script can be as simple as the following:

```
$!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob    # To return nothing if there is no match.
echo *$1*
```

Then just call it as `script.sh questi`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using `find`:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -iname "*questi*"
```

The option `-type f` results in only files being returned and `-iname` does a case insensitive match on the glob `*questi*`, so should return 'question1.txt','five_questions.txt' etc.

If you wish you can put this in a shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
find $1 -type f -iname "*$2*"
```

And call it like: `filefind.sh /path/to/directory questi`